# Meteor 0.8.x namespacing

Tags: javascript, node.js, namespaces, meteor, directory-structure

### Background Info

I've witnessed that Meteor wraps each file into an anonymous function to prevent filling up the global namespace.

Assume that I have a similar file structure:

- ***client/***

  - index.html
  - style.css
  - client.js
  - ***helpers/***

    - somehelper.js
- ***server/***

  - server.js
- ***models/***

  - ...

---

### My Questions

1. How can I use objects that are in ***somehelper.js*** from the file ***client.js***?
2. How can I create my own namespaces? For example: `client`, `client.helpers`, `models` and `server`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right! Each file has it's own local namespace. To define a global variable you would need to drop the leading `var`. A common practice to prevent polluting your global namespace is to have a single global object, e.g. `App`, to host all globally-scoped symbols. This object can defined in the top level `lib` folder to overcome some file-loading-order related issues.

If for some reason your code depends on the file loading order, you can wrap some parts of it within `Meteor.startup` routine to prevent undefined-type-errors.

Another possible solution - if like modules and stuff like that - would be to use some AMD-imitating tool for **Meteor** like [this one](https://github.com/apendua/require) for example.

Comment: Concerning [define](http://atmospherejs.com/package/define), if I  have a file `helperA` and a file `helperB`, can I reuse `define()` in both files to add them both in the same module?

Comment: I don't believe that modules can be spitted in to several files if that's what you're asking about. But there are certainly ways to achieve what you want here.